# file/folder is already in use, renaming,deletion problem ? c# iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to renme a file/folder, when i try to rename a file, i got an error, file is already in use, it is just my guess that it is caused by w3wp.exe iis process? some time its says, access to the path is denied, although the file does exist, and there are no special permission, i have all the permission to copy/delete/move and everything for the file/folder.
How to fix this problem.

**the folder contains jpeg files.
this happen: when i copy a file then try to rename it.
this happen: when i rename a file then try to delete it.**
what i mean to say is that it happen when i already use a file operation then for second time it gives me this error :(
this is the error:
**The process cannot access the file 'C:\images\audio-aif-old.png' because it is being used by another process.**

```
file.move(source,destination);
```

i am using C#. iis 6, asp.net.

Comment: Are you doing something else with that file before you try to move it?

Comment: What file are you trying to move? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @alexn, yes, this happen if i copy a file/folder and then try to rename it, this happen when i rename a file/folder then try to delete it, even if i rename a file/folder then try to delete it then it also happen.

Comment: Have you checked that the move works correctly when done on its own?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you can't even rename the file in windows explorer?

Comment: @djerry yes, when i got this error i try to rename the file in the explorer as well but i cant.

Comment: then the problem is not in your code, but your program being used by another program. Try rebooting and renaming that specific file again. The rebooting should release your file.

Comment: @djerry, yes you are right, i reboot the system, some time i clear the cache and close the browser, but the process w3wp i.e iis does not release the file,until i logoff or restart browser or system.

Comment: @djerry, can you see the question now?

Comment: i see what you are saying, but i'm inexperienced concerning iis, so i don't know if that keeps your file busy after calling it the first time. If it does not release it automatically, you might try releasing it manually, if that is supported, but again, i don't know if iis supports that.

Answer (score 1):

Directly , ans is no. But you can delete old copy and create a new copy. See this. http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/file/file-renfile-aspnet2-csharp.aspx

Comment: well this is how i am doing, but if i try to make a file operation for second time than i got this eroor>?

Comment: ok.. make sure the image is not referenced in the current running form/page. If its not then you can move/delete

Comment: yeah i have make sure, specially this happen in case of renaming folder.

Answer (score 0):

Some other program must relinquish the file. If you've written a program that's still running then that must be shut down. If the file is currently open for writing you must also ensure that it's been appropriately closed. Try creating another file and see if you have the same problem with that one.

Comment: This problem happen when i rename a file, then for the 2nd time if i try to delete it then it happen, and same is for copy and for delete.